# Dask and Numba - How to use map partitions efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, numba

I'm trying to speed up my code and improve my understanding of Dask and Numba, I did try to use both on some example I created yet there is no improvement and I can't understand why.

I must say  that I'm on on a laptop with four cores so the improvement might not be large but it should be there nonetheless.

More precisely on a Windows 10 laptop, using Python 3.7 and having Numba and Dask in a conda environment.

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import jit
import dask.dataframe as dd

data = np.random.randint(-10, 10, (10**8, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["A", "B", "C"], index=None)
df["F"] = np.random.choice(["apple", "banana", "orange", 
                            "pear","grape","lime","citrus","peach"],10**8)
```

As you can see it's quite a big dataframe memory wise, this was my way to check if Dask represented on improvement or not. On smaller dataframes (< 200MB) it didn't seem to make a difference at all.

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=12)

@jit
def remove_special_char_with_numba(x):
    return x.replace('r','')
```

This is a toy example where I try to remove a string from a specific column, Numba does speed up the code compared to vanilla Pandas but doesn't support strings so I can't modify *replace* or use the nopython mode.
Now :

```
%%timeit
remove_special_char_with_numba(df["F"])
```

output :

> 58.9 s ± 9.51 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Next, my understanding of the following is that Dask separated my dataframe into different chunks/partitions and that it will apply the function on each separated chunk independently. With four cores, it should speed up the process as far as I understand it.

```
%%timeit
ddf["F"].map_partitions(remove_special_char_with_numba).compute()
```

output :

> 45.9 s ± 10.5 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Now I don't want to be greedy but shouldn't the improvement be larger than that? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This result should not surprise you too much. You are, apparently, running on the default threaded scheduler.

That means that every string operation must obtain the single python GIL in order to happen, and that is true whether it is in dask-controled worker threads. That remains true for the numba-jit version of the operation, because you cannot run this function in no-python mode. If it *were* in no-python mode, it would release the GIL, and full string support will be coming to numba.

You might be able to get a better speedup using the distributed scheduler with a number of processes, although then you suffer the costs of sending data between processes, so it matters how you generate the data, and the fact that you bring all of the results into the main session when you `compute()`.

Comment: I didn't find a way to use nopython and I don't seem that it it possible for string operations. I did try some transformations to boolean but replacing a specific string by another proves to be problematic.

Is there a way to compute it in a better fashion such that I get a better improvement? I didn't understand the arguments for the _compute_ method so well so I left it as is. Is there somewhere, a slightly dumb down version I could get ahold of to read about Dask?

Thanks

Comment: 1) experiment with the distributed scheduler, varying the number of processes; 2) numba can't help you (yet), but you could write cython if you really wanted to; 3) as always, you are better do s8 something with your data in their partitions rather than gather all results to a pandas dataframe

Comment: Alright, so I should apply the function to each partitions and only once it is done return it to a pandas dataframe? Is my understanding wrong that this is what I did in the code above though?

Alright I'll look into the scheduler to see if there is more to be done

Comment: Short story: if something works well with pandas in-memory, you will be hard pressed to beat it ever. Avoiding the GIL comes with communication costs or moving to different technology. This is beyond what can fit in an answer here.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep playing around and see where it goes. Thanks for your help!